# How to write a function that accepts a tuple that contains integer elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a function `average` that accepts a `tuple` that contains integer elements as an argument and returns the average value of the elements within the argument.

```
for example, average((1, 2, 3)) = 2
for example, average((-3, 2, 8, -1)) = 1.5
```

my answer:

```
def average(values):
    if values == (1,2,3):
        return (1+2+3)/3
    elif values == (-3,2,8,-1):
        return (-3+2+8-1)/4
```

Why wrong? How to do?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function only works for those two specific inputs. The goal is to write a function that returns the correct average for all valid inputs.

You should use python's builtin functions [sum](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#sum) and [len](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#len) for this

```
def average(values):
    return sum(values)/len(values)
```

For Python 2 you have to wrap the `sum(values)` (or the `len(values)`, either part of the division is good) inside a call to `float`.

Starting with Python 3.4 you can use the function [mean from the statistics module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean).

```
import statistics
def average(values):
    return statistics.mean(values)
```

or shorter as your function is just another name for statistic's mean

```
average = statistics.mean
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
In [1]: def average(values):
   ...:     return float(sum(values))/len(values)
   ...:

In [2]: print average((-3,2,8,-1))
1.5
```

Add a `float` to the `sum` function to work for Python 2.

Comment: As the questions is tagged `python3` the call to float is unnecessary as the normal division in Python3 already does float division